# How to edit template-instance of start workflow page in Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I want to add a upload button the start-workflow page and for that i need to add upload component xml tags as follows in template instance:

```
  <component>
     <region-id>html-upload</region-id>
     <url>/components/upload/html-upload</url>
  </component>
  <component>
     <region-id>flash-upload</region-id>
     <url>/components/upload/flash-upload</url>
  </component>
  <component>
     <region-id>file-upload</region-id>
     <url>/components/upload/file-upload</url>
  </component>
  <component>
     <region-id>dnd-upload</region-id>
     <url>/components/upload/dnd-upload</url>
  </component>
  <component>
     <region-id>archive-and-download</region-id>
     <url>/components/download/archive</url>
  </component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you wanted to add a upload button to the start-workflow page alfresco OOTB provides the workflow package you can attach your documents here.
You just need to define it in share config

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$submitDocument">
        <forms>
            <form>
                <field-visibility>

                    <show id="packageItems" />

                </field-visibility>
                <appearance>
                    <set id="general" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />
                     <field id="packageItems" set="general" label="Purchase request document">
                        <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/packageitems.ftl">
                        </control>
                   </field>
                </appearance>
            </form>
        </forms>
    </config>
```

and you can get all the attached document using javascript

```
var documents = bpm_package.children;
```

Comment: i know about that and it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Can you please explain what you exactly wants to do ?

Comment: thanks for your interest. for my requirements, user needs to be able to  directly upload to start-workflow page. quick question :"How to specify the destination or directory of user home while uploading? I am having difficulty getting noderefs?"

Comment: you can create a custom webscript which will return the userhome noderef.
alfresco script provides userhome object.

Comment: please help me on this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605189/how-can-i-define-departments-in-alfresco-such-that-outgoing-document-for-one-dep @vikash

Comment: do you have any experience using community edition  of alfresco in production? if yes, what problems did you come across?

Comment: @She yes, what is your problem? can you please explain?

Comment: well i'm afraid about scalability problems. It's going to be roughly 100 users for now. But they may plan on adding offices and what if we have to do clustering?

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple and obvious as it could have been. All you need to do is create a file named start-workflow.xml in the directory src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/template-instances. Then just copy paste the original file and add your components. This isn't enough in itself. You also have to add regions of these components to the template of start-workflow. Again, a simple process. Create a file start-workflow.ftl in the directory src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/templates/org/alfresco. Once again copy paste the original file and add your regions. In my case it was :

```
    <@region id="html-upload" scope="template"/>
    <@region id="flash-upload" scope="template"/>
    <@region id="file-upload" scope="template"/>
    <@region id="dnd-upload" scope="template"/>
    <@region id="archive-and-download" scope="template"/>
```